# Book where where all electricity is destroyed in an instant and magic starts to change people

Tags: story-identification, books, post-apocalyptic

I have read this book a few years ago, maybe 10 years, but I can not remember the title or the author, but it was based in present time and in an instant the world changed (a nuclear type bomb took out technology) and no technology, but not only that people were changing into magical creatures because magic is now in the world, but not all of it good.

One of the characters a young girl, starts to change into fairy along with other teens. another group of characters are miners and some of them start to change into "mole men". Anyone who starts to change is being changed by an entity that either came into being with the end of technolgy or it was always there but had a hand in the destruction of the world by having a group of scientist create some type of wormhole. The entity I believe eats the fairy kids as it speaks to them to come to him.

It has been awhile but that is the gist and I would love it if anyone knows this series. I find myself wanting to read it again.

Answer (score 5):

The book is called *[Magic Time](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1239560.Magic_Time)*. There are two sequels to it, *Angelfire* and *Ghostlands*.

> For rising young lawyer Cal Griffin, it's just another day in the Big City--until the lights go off...for good. Suddenly packs of pale crouched figures are stalking the darkened subways, monsters prowl Times Square, and the people all around Cal are...changing. Similar weirdness is happening everywhere, from the dank, cold heart of a West Virginia coal mine to a remote lab in South Dakota--where a team of government scientists has unwittingly invited something catastrophic into the world--to the highest levels of power in Washington, D.C.

Comment: OMG thank you! As soon as I saw the main characters name I knew this was it and I knew there had to be sequels!

Comment: You are welcome. I also thank Sean Duggan for editing my answer to make it sound a lot better then what I had originally typed.